# How to create a remote viewer for a games LAN party?

Tags: c++, c, windows, remote-desktop

In my LAN I have 11 computers for **multiplayer games LAN parties**.

I need to create a **remote viewer** for all 10 computers in my LAN.

So this program only **needs to captures and sends the desktop** to my computer.

What API, functions or library do I have to use ?

.

P.s. I want create my own program, so I don't want to use other programs like RealVNC.

P.p.s. I want create only a remote viewer program and **NOT** a remote control program.

Comment: Can you use extra hardware like some HDMI-capture device in another computer? Or do you need pure software solution? Pure software capture will affect performance of games and/or stream quality.

Comment: Capturing a screen and sending it to another computer in real-time is going to kill any time the application may have had to run. That said, you *may* have a chance if you can get direct access to the back-buffer being rendered to, have a *quick* (multi-threaded) compression algorithm that runs during vertical-sync, then sends while the next frame is being processed by the game. *Maybe.*

Comment: What software is applicable, then? Are libraries allowed, or do you need to build this whole thing from scratch? (including the OS ;o)) No, seriously: if you don't want to *use* the software that deals with this, you should at least check their code (where allowed) to see what they did, what not, and why (if there's documentation or changelogs) - chances are, the people who wrote VNC servers/clients have encountered similar problems that you're going to encounter.

Comment: Usually this is the job of the multiplayer game server. It has all the data and is therefore able to send a data stream to game client showing a spectator view that is equal to one shown to one of the players.

Comment: I need only a pure software solution. The Performances doesn't matter :)

Comment: @xRobot: A multiplayer game LAN where "performance doesn't matter" - that's a first! :)

Comment: @Robert: AFAICT, that's not how it works in practice. The normal "spectator" view is usually rendered client-side, by a stripped-down game client. But yeah, it does help to have the spectators connect to the game server directly.

Comment: the games are very very simple ( like chess game ) so the performances doesn't matter. I need only to know what API, function or library I have to use to captures and sends the desktop to my computer :)

Comment: @MSalters Thats what I described. The game server sends the game data to to the game client (i did not say screenshots or images!). If the client is stripped-down or not doesn't matter.

Comment: @Robert ok but I need to create it in C or C++. I don't want to use external program :)

Comment: What game exactly are you talking about?

Comment: @xRobot: Platform, vendor, version of the software?

Comment: @Robert It's written by me :)

Comment: @xRobot: Then what is your problem? Just create a viewer that does not allow to perform moves and connect it via TCP to the server/main game.

Comment: @Robert What Api, function o library I have to use for capture and sends the desktop to my computer ?

Comment: @xRobot: Don't capture the desktop. Just send data containing the chess board and which figure is on which position to the spectator client. In the client use the same code for generating the visible chess board as in the regular client.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can give you some advice for Windows platform and Borland Builder C++. You'll need two applications, one installed at client side and one in your side.

Client side

1. A TCP server listening for your command request.
2. An UDP client to send screenshot to your side.
3. Screenshot grabber, you can do it by sending a print-scrn message to windows and then grabbing from clipboard, converting to a jpg and send an UDP packet. You'll need to experiment different image resolutions and compress schemes to obtain a good trade in between quality and transfer speed, I don't think its a big issue with today networks.

Your side

1. A TCP Client to send your command request for a screenshot.
2. An UDP listening endpoint to receive screenshot.

If you are into C++ or Delphi, you could use Indy project components for that, its really very easy, they have many examples of UDP ad TCP client-server apps one can use to develop such kind of tool, check at www.indyproject.org and remember that Google is your best friend for this.

Comment: This is not THAT hard to implement and has been done before, anyone knows punkbuster?  they have a solution that do screen captures and search your memory for possible resident cheat tools, all at the same time with online game itself and running on client side.